# Can I disable "write-cache buffer flushing" for an Intel 730 SSD on a desktop PC

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, power, ups

Can I disable "write-cache buffer flushing" for an Intel 730 SSD on a desktop PC without UPS? This drive has capacitors for power-loss protection - is this enough to flush the buffers when a power loss occurs?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the power-loss protection for SSD's is somewhat over exaggerated and does not work as advertised in reality, although better than not having power-loss protection it certainly does not complete eliminate the risk of loss data if a power outage occurs whilst the drive is in use (we rolled out around 400 SSD's in an office environment and paid premium for power-loss protection but it still occurred with power cut/outages).

You can disable write cache buffer from the device manager, simply load device manager > expand Disk Drives > right click your drive and properties > check for the setting under policies.

The only real protection is with a desktop UPS (under desk one) which are great for not only preventing data loss but also the health of your machine overall.

Edit:

Your post did spark my interest and upon reading a review of some of the newer Intel drives it does seem a lot more reliable than previous (my experience was from SSD's around 3 years ago).

Quote: Continuing with the enterprise features, there is full power-loss protection similar to what's in the S3500/S3700. I'm surprised that we've seen so few client SSDs with power-loss protection. Given the recent studies of power-loss bricking SSDs, power-loss protection should make a good feature at least in the high-end SSDs.

Question is do you trust it? It is hard to advise either way.

Comment: Which SSDs have you used (I'm asking about these "400 SSD's in office environment")? I previously had a Samsung 830 and it would cause logical errors after power loss even with only "write-caching" enabled (had to do "Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth" to repair it). Now I'm using the Intel 730 and had no problems with "write-caching" enabled and thought to push it harder with disabling "write-cache buffer flushing".

Comment: These were very early SanDisk drives that came with Data Loss Protection. They were small drives used for OS only but we found we had to reinstall a number of them after any power incidents due to corrupt OS. From what I'm reading here the new Intel disks look to be really good, they are kept alive in power loss situations by power-loss protection is provided by two 47 microfarad 35V capacitors which means they should be kept alive to flush the full cache to disk. Again hard to give you 100% advise but I would leave the flushing on. What exactly are you looking to gain from disabling it speed?

Comment: Yes, speed. But I guess I will benchmark it first, to see if it;s worth it.

Comment: Yeah I would say benchmark before and after, if the gains are minimal which I think you'll find they will be then leave it enabled. Problem is that you will find with the Intel drives is that turning off these extra features to gain more speed will soon start to hit the SATA 3 bottleneck.